# Log requests to nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express, logging

I want to log all requests like this:

`8:04:20 PM - info: /api/v2 200
8:04:22 PM - info: /api/v2/asdf 200`

However, in express, the middleware is called before the request is processed, so I cannot get the real response code. I always get 200. What is the right approach to accomplish this?

Comment: I believe express exposes a few log features. I think you have expose an environment variable `DEBUG=express:*` and as far as I can tell that logs to the system output all requests. See [Debugging Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html)

Answer (score 8):

You can use morgan to log your requests:

```
const morgan = require("morgan");
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

For more documentation visit [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan). Yo may also be interested in 
[on-finished](https://github.com/jshttp/on-finished) package to execute arbitrary code on request completion.

Answer (score 7):

Here you go:

```
app.use((req, res, next)=> {
  console.log('I run on every request!');
  next();
})
```

Comment: On every "good" request. I came here because I was trying to troubleshoot a 400 Bad Request. It would be good to know how to get every bad request to fire something as well.

Answer (score 1):

As Edwin said, you could do the same without modifying your code using DEBUG environment variable, like this :

```
DEBUG=express:* && node server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your middleware below your routes and in your routes add a third parameter on the callback like this:

```
app.get( "/", function( req, res, next ) {
  res.send(something);
  next();
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('after request is done');
});
```